# How to read 'n' following tags after each selected node

Tags: vb.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get each player stats from the following HTML table using VB .NET and HTML Agility Pack (HAP), but I don't know how to select the  tags after each player row.

```
    <table class="stats" cellspacing="0">
   <tr class="statsgreen">
      <td colspan="10" class="estverdel">Team A</td>
      <td colspan="2">REB</td>
      <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="2">BLK</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="2">PF</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="statsgreen">
      <td>Num</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Min</td>
      <td>GS</td>
      <td>T2</td>
      <td>T2 %</td>
      <td>T3</td>
      <td>T3 %</td>
      <td>T1</td>
      <td>T1 %</td>
      <td>T</td>
      <td>D+O</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>ST</td>
      <td>LO</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>R</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td>R</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>+/-</td>
      <td>PIE</td>
   </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td><a href="/player.php?id=001">Player 1</a></td>
      <td>30:22</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>4/10</td>
      <td>40%</td>
      <td>2/6</td>
      <td>33%</td>
      <td>4/4</td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>5+4</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>20</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td><a href="/player.php?id=002">Player 2</a></td>
      <td>30:22</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>4/10</td>
      <td>40%</td>
      <td>2/6</td>
      <td>33%</td>
      <td>4/4</td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>5+4</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>20</td>
   </tr>
   ...
   ...
   <tr class="statsgreen">
      <td colspan="10" class="estverdel">Team B</td>
      <td colspan="2">REB</td>
      <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="2">BLK</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="2">PF</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="statsgreen">
      <td>Num</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Min</td>
      <td>GS</td>
      <td>T2</td>
      <td>T2 %</td>
      <td>T3</td>
      <td>T3 %</td>
      <td>T1</td>
      <td>T1 %</td>
      <td>T</td>
      <td>D+O</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>ST</td>
      <td>LO</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>R</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td>R</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>+/-</td>
      <td>PIE</td>
   </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td><a href="/player.php?id=013">Player 13</a></td>
      <td>30:22</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>4/10</td>
      <td>40%</td>
      <td>2/6</td>
      <td>33%</td>
      <td>4/4</td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>5+4</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>20</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This is my uncomplete code in VB.NET only getting the teams and the player names:

```
Private Sub btnGetStats_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetStats.Click
    Dim doc As New HtmlDocument                    
    doc.Load("C:\001.html")

    'Get team names  
    For Each nodeteams As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class=""estverdel""]")                    
        MessageBox.Show("Team: " + nodeteams.InnerText)                
    Next

    'Get player names
    For Each nodeplayers As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href, '/player')]")
        MessageBox.Show(nodeplayers.InnerText)    
    Next
End Sub
```

Is there any XPATH sentence I could use for selecting each player node and then go through each one of the following 21 stats fields?.

As an alternative I suppose I could get the nodeplayers.line and then read the following 21 lines using System.IO.StreamReader but maybe HAP can do it in a smart way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to use `ParentNode` property of the `HtmlNode` player object:

- take the parent of the parent of the found player node (the tr node from `<tr><td><a player>...`)
- take all child nodes (all `td` nodes)
- skip the first two of the child nodes using [LINQ Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (the number and the player link)
- take the rest of the child nodes

Modifying your second loop like this:

```
   'Get player names
   for each nodeplayers as HtmlNode in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href, '/player')]")
        Console.WriteLine("Player: " + nodeplayers.InnerText)
        ' select parent node (tr) of player (a) parent node (td), skip first two and take the rest 
        for each node as HtmlNode in nodeplayers.ParentNode.ParentNode.ChildNodes.Skip(2).ToList()
            Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText)
        next
   next
```

returns all values for each player:

```
Team: Team A
Team: Team B
Player: Player 1   
30:22  
18
4/10 
40% 
2/6
33% 
4/4
100% 
9 
5+4  
1  
1 
0    
0   
0  
0    
0    
3    
4    
10    
20
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much @pasty! It works, although nodes.count = 47. It is getting some strange 'vblf + "     "' maybe because of the format between the tags. So the even nodes are scrap and the odd ones contain the data. It is not a big issue so I can adapt my code. Thank you again @pasty!

Comment: Glad that the answer helped.